# How to use Arabic text inside addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, arabic

I am using arabxetex package. I need my TOP be all in Arabic script including page numbers. \addcontentsline works with Latin [English] text, but not with Arabic.

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{-- TEXT-- }
```

When I use something like this inside the TEXT brackets:

```
\begin{arab}[utf]
ببي
\end{arab}
```

It gives me error.

Need your help. As per request, here I am adding complete working minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage[margin=0.08in, paperwidth=3.56in, paperheight=5.95in]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{AAA} % Instead of AAA, I need Arabic text ننن
\begin{arab}[utf]
نتنتنهه
\end{arab}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{BBB} % Instead of BBB, I need Arabic text ههه
\begin{arab}[utf]
منسة
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a complete minimal example, with the class and the necessary packages. In any case, try preceding `\begin` and `\end` with `\protect`.

Comment: I added complete minimal example. I have also tried \protect but it gives error. I want TOC be completely in Arabic language [RTL script]; both the section titles and page numbers. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is you document entirely in Arabic?

Comment: Yes, it is, except for the commands.

Comment: The partial answer to my question is to use: `\textarab[utf]`. Now the question is : How can I to turn TOC page numbers into Arabic script?

Comment: @Nina: I recommend to reduce your question to one local problem and ask a new question which refers to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need `arabxetex`? The following typesets without glitches:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Scheherazade}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ننن}

نتنتنهه

\section{ههه}

منسة

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but since I am using different special Arabic font for each and every page, setting \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Some Special Arabic Fonts} in your code does not compile.

Comment: Hi egreg. I appreciate your help, but the code you provided with isn't compatible with multiple non-package special fonts. Can you extend your help please.

Comment: @Nina Sorry, but I'm no expert in Arabic. And your example doesn't show anything of that kind.

Comment: You don't have to. Just share your ingenious expertise in TEX how to implement \begin{arab}[utf]نتعه\end{arab} clause inside my arabxetex file to have TOC appear all in Arabic script. Waiting for your solution, please :)

Comment: egreg, I found the solution i.e is to use \textarab[utf] inside the text bracket. However, page numbers still show in Latin, not in Arabic language. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using "a different font for every page?" Or a different font for *all* pages? If you use fontspec, there's an option to use:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq] {arabic}
```

But I'm not sure at all if it works, because the code without compiles just fine.